# A function which will display the contents of an array being sorted c++ using insertion sort

Tags: c++, arrays, function, sorting, insertion

I have error, which is highlighted "cout << array[i] << endl;" in this section. The line is under array[i]. The error is "argument list for class template "std::array" is missing ". i need a function to display the contents of an array, using an insertion sort. If this code is incorrect, does anyone know the code to output the contents of the array, using linear search.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    int numbers[SIZE] = { 6,3,1,9,4,12,17,2 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}

const int SIZE = 8;
void insertionSort(int numbers[], int arraySize)
{
    int i, j, insert;

    for (i = 1; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        insert = numbers[i];
        j = i;
        while ((j > 0) && (numbers[j - 1] > insert))
        {
            numbers[j] = numbers[j - 1];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        numbers[j] = insert;

    }
}
```

Comment: try `cout << numbers[i] << endl;` and `SIZE` should be defined before `main`.

Comment: @knivil thank you that worked

Comment: Also note that `std::array` is a class in the standard library, and by `using namespace std;` you've thrown it into global scope, which makes using the identifier `array` when you meant something else potentially an error.

Comment: @knivil when i run the program the array is not sorted, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't call your function `insertionSort(int numbers[], int arraySize)` in `main()`. Therefore nothing will happen to the original array.

Note that you need a `return 0;` statement inside `int main()`. And that you need to use `numbers[i]` instead of `array[i]`. And you need to set your `insertionSort(`) to `return` "something" or to pass your `numbers[]` as a reference. Also not to forget about the function prototype before `main().`

This should work:

```
const int SIZE = 8;
void insertionSort(int [], int);

int main()
{
    int numbers[SIZE] = { 6,3,1,9,4,12,17,2 };
    insertionSort(numbers, SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        cout << numbers[i] << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void insertionSort(int MyArray[], int size)
{
    int i, j, insert;

    for (i = 1; i < size; i++){
        insert = MyArray[i];
        j = i;
        while ((j > 0) && (MyArray[j - 1] > insert)){
            MyArray[j] = MyArray[j - 1];
            j = j - 1;}
        MyArray[j] = insert;}
}
```